# How to keep running apollo subscription while capacitor app is on background?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, capacitor

I been developing a react.js chat application which works via websocket connection with apollo-client.It uses [capacitor.js](https://capacitorjs.com/) to create cross-platform iOS, Android, and Progressive Web Apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. In chat component, a subscription query starts works and listen new for new messages. The problem is that messages are not listening while the app is in the background. New messages starts loaded as soon as open app.I want to make it like whatsapp which load new messages while even app is on background.

Apollo client configuration

```
const wsLink = process.browser
  ? new SubscriptionClient(WEBSOCKET_URL, {
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: () => ({
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${readLocalStorage('id_token')}`,
          'x-hasura-admin-secret':
            'xxxx',
        },
      }),
    })
  : null;
```

Component which subscription works

```
const onSubscriptionData = useCallback(
    ({ subscriptionData: { data } }: OnSubscriptionDataOptions<any>) => {
      if (selectedChatId.current) {
        setMessages([...(data.conversation || {})]);
        markAsRead();
      }
    },
    [selectedChatId.current]
  );

  const { loading: messagesLoading } = useSubscription(MESSAGE_DETAIL_SUBSCRIPTION, {
    onSubscriptionData,
    variables: {
      chat_thread_id: selectedChatId,
      user_id: user_id,
    },
  });
```

Also capacitor has [background plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/background-task)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is Push Notifications ([@capacitor/push_notifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications)).

When a subscription happens in your server (eg. new message) you then send a push notification to your devices. The push notification will be displayed in the device and when you click/open the app you can fetch new data from the server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).